# Using a ternary operator in a map function is rendering both results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, popover

I'm creating a vertical timeline with cards alternating sides as you move along the timeline, I'm trying to include a Popover effect to show more info about a person/event that fills the opposite whitespace on the timeline.

I'm trying to achieve this by using a ternary operator (using modulus to alternate sides in order) in my map callback, but it's rendering/returning both possible Popover results, onClick leads to a Popover popping on both sides of the card.

```
render() {
    const cards = timelineObjects.map((card, i) => (
      <React.Fragment key={i}>

        {i % 2 === 0 ? (
          <VerticalTimelineElement
            className="vertical-timeline-element--work"
            key={i}
            iconStyle={{
              background: "rgb(40,49,72)",
              color: "#000"
            }}
            paddingTop="0em"

            //icon={<Print/>}
          >
            <div>
              <Card className="card">
                <CardActionArea>
                  <CardMedia
                    style={{ height: 0, paddingTop: "100%" }}
                    image={card.image}
                  />
                  <CardContent>
                    <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                      {card.title}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography component="p">{card.subtitle}</Typography>
                  </CardContent>
                </CardActionArea>

                <Button
                  size="small"
                  color="primary"
                  component={Link}
                  //to={card.path}
                  onClick={this.handlePop}
                >
                  Learn More, index: {i}, RIGHT
                </Button>
                <Popover
                  open={this.state.popped}
                  anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl}
                  anchorOrigin={{
                    horizontal: "right",
                    vertical: "center "
                  }}
                  transformOrigin={{
                    horizontal: "right",
                    vertical: "bottom"
                  }}
                  onClose={this.handleRequestClose}
                >
                  Right popover text
                </Popover>
              </Card>
            </div>
          </VerticalTimelineElement>
        ) 
        : 

        (
          <VerticalTimelineElement
            className="vertical-timeline-element--work"
            key={i}
            iconStyle={{
              background: "rgb(40,49,72)",
              color: "#000"
            }}
            paddingTop="0em"

            //icon={<Print/>}
          >
            <div>
              <Card className="card">
                <CardActionArea>
                  <CardMedia
                    style={{ height: 0, paddingTop: "100%" }}
                    image={card.image}
                  />
                  <CardContent>
                    <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                      {card.title}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography component="p">{card.subtitle}</Typography>
                  </CardContent>
                </CardActionArea>

                <Button
                  size="small"
                  color="primary"
                  component={Link}
                  //to={card.path}
                  onClick={this.handlePop}
                >
                  Learn More, index : {i}, LEFT
                </Button>
                <Popover
                  open={this.state.popped}
                  anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl}
                  anchorOrigin={{
                    horizontal: "left",
                    vertical: "center "
                  }}
                  transformOrigin={{
                    horizontal: "left",
                    vertical: "bottom"
                  }}
                  onClose={this.handleRequestClose}
                >
                  Left popover text
                </Popover>
              </Card>
            </div>
          </VerticalTimelineElement>
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    ));
```

[Here's a screen grab of the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvOUR.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your popovers are all anchored to the same element (`this.state.anchorEl`) and are all configured to open based upon the same boolean (`this.state.popped`).  This means if you have 2+ objects in your timeline, you render a popover for each object, and all popovers will be opened or closed together and all will be to the left/right of the only anchor element (whatever that is).

You should probably create a new `TimelineObject` component that renders a single timeline object and can have its own local state and assigns its own local `anchorEl` to anchor its popover to.  Possibly its own `popped` state as well.  Then your map function would be more like:

`timelineObjects.map((card, i) => <TimelineObject key={i} card={card} onLeft={i%2==0} />)`

Alternatively, instead of using `this.state.popped` as a boolean, use it as the card index to show the popup for.  And in your `Popover` code do:

`<Popover open={this.state.popped === i} ...`

And when you set `popped` set it like `this.setState({popped: indexOfCardToShowPopover, anchorEl: elementOfCardToAnchorPopover });`

That way only 1 popover is ever open at a time.

Comment: Thank you, Brandon! This helped.